# What's the difference between "Standort" and "Ort"?

Tags: difference

Are they interchangeable, I don't understand what adding "Stand" does to "Ort" that makes it a compound word that is different from "Ort".

Comment: This question is not entirely *off topic* as all dictionaries have a considerable overlap in translating *Ort* and *Standort* which leads to the impression they may be interchangeable or synonyms. To get it reopened and to get an answer that meets you concern best please [edit] your question to give us **results of your research**, and why they did not help you in the **context** you are looking for. If you have merely an interest in the role of the prefix *Stand-* you may want to add additional examples to make that clearer.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between both is probably best described by translating them into a similar pair in English:

> Ort – place
>   Standort – location

Two examples you might come across in daily life:

> Teile deinen Standort in Whatsapp. (Share your location in Whatsapp.)

and

> Ich war schon an diesem Ort. (I have been to this place before.)

Of course you could say: "I've been to this location", but I would argue it's not as widely used. However, in German you wouldn't say "Ich war an diesem Standort" (except when talking about a military or a business context).

Answer (score 0):

A **Standort** is a place where a person or a facility is located.

> Wir treffen uns an diesem Ort.

*We are going to meet at that place.*

> Wir treffen uns an diesem Standort.

*We are going to meet at that site.*

> Standort

*Your position* (legend for red dot on public map displays)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between "Ort" and "Standort" is mostly one of perspective. "Ort" is a general term for a place. "Standort" has a narrower focus on a place as the location *of* something else.

For example, in

> Sie hatte den Ort oft besucht.

"Ort" denotes a place in and of itself.

> Sie kannte den Standort der neuen Fabrik noch aus ihrer Kindheit.

"Standort" defines the place by saying it's the location of the new factory.